# Change matplotlib annotation arrowstyle class attributes

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, cartopy

I annotated my map under use of `arrowstyle="simple"`. According to the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch), the arrowstyle `simple` has the following attributes: `head_length=0.5, head_width=0.5, tail_width=0.2`. Can I still somehow manipualte the attributes of the class manually? e.g. I would like to have a simple bend arrow where I can adjust the `tail_width` as in `wedge` and other parameters such as `head_length` and `head_width`.

[image]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

east = 15.6562839 # max -180
west = 5.0506635 # max 180
north = 55.3841673 # max 90
south = 47.1113124 # max -90

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([west, east, south, north])
ax.stock_img()

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

berlin_lon, berlin_lat = 13.388889, 52.516667
aachen_lon, aachen_lat = 6.083611, 50.775556


#https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html
ax.annotate('20kg',
            xy=(berlin_lon, berlin_lat),
            xytext=(aachen_lon, aachen_lat),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple",
                            connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.4",
                            linewidth=1,
                            ), 
            )

plt.show()
```

Comment: `arrowstyle="simple,head_length=3,head_width=5",`

Comment: Thank you very much! That already helps. But I then assume, it is not possible to apply attributes of `wedge` on `simple` ...

Comment: You can check with the respective classes [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.Wedge) to see which attributes are available.